# why read() behaviour changed after redirection?

Tags: c, linux, redirect

I have encountered a problem while programming in Linux using C, and I have narrowed it down to the following question.

```
#define BUF_SIZE 10

int main()
{
        int cnt;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        cnt = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        printf("cnt = %d\n", cnt);
        return 0;
}
```

Given the code above, if I use the terminal as input, and put in 3 characters and then hit enter, then I got "cnt = 4".

```
./a.out 
abc
cnt = 4
```

But if I use redirection, and use a file, which contains two lines, as the input, `read()` does not stop at the newline character, but proceed and read the whole file. Like this

```
//inside input_file. This line is not in the file.
123
456
```

Then I got

```
./a.out < input_file
cnt = 8
```

Now here is my question. Why `read()` does not stop after reading the first line in the file ? What is the difference between a terminal input and a file input ?

Some references to explain this would be appreciated.

Comment: [read() from stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975521/read-from-stdin)