# Why is the read() returning an incorrect byte count?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Given the following code for application `read-data` which simply reads data from `stdin` into a buffer `buf` allocated on the heap:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const size_t BUF_SIZE=1048576*256; // Just for testing, don't do this in prod code
const size_t MAX_READ_SIZE=1048576;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Allocate buffer space on the heap
    char *buf=(char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);

    // Check for malloc failure
    if (buf==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to allocate %zu bytes\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t curOffset=0;

    // Read MAX_READ_SIZE (or smaller) blocks until EOF
    // WARNING: Don't do this in actual "live" code, since it can result
    // in a buffer overflow with an input whose size
    // exceeds that of the pre-allocated buffer
    while (ssize_t numRead=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+curOffset,MAX_READ_SIZE)>0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Bytes read: %zu\n",numRead);
        curOffset+=numRead;
    }

    // Free buffer space
    free(buf);
    fprintf(stderr,"Total bytes read: %zu\n",curOffset);
}
```

Test:

```
$ cat | ./read-data
a
Bytes read: 1
b
Bytes read: 1
c
Bytes read: 1
d
Bytes read: 1
Total bytes read: 4
```

Where are all the newlines and their "bytes" going? There should have been two bytes read per input and 8 bytes total.

Compare for example with:

Test using basic Unix tools:

```
$ cat | printf 'Total bytes read: %u\n' "$(wc --bytes)"
a
b
c
d
Total bytes read: 8
```

What's even stranger is that given a file `four-lines.txt`, I have even crazier behavior:

```
$ cat four-lines.txt
a
b
c
d
$ wc --bytes four-lines.txt
8 four-lines.txt
$ <four-lines.txt ./read-data
Bytes read: 1
Total bytes read: 1
```

The bug must be obvious, but all I can say is: *WTF?*

Update: As Andrew pointed out, the bug is an issue of incorrect assumption of operator precedence in the line:

```
    while (ssize_t numRead=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+curOffset,MAX_READ_SIZE)>0)
```

Is there a way to change the line so that the definition can be placed within the `while` condition or is it necessary to define numRead before the `while`?

Update 2: And the fix is obvious, thanks `WhozCraig` for your answer that keeps the variable definition scoped to the body of the loop:

```
for (ssize_t numRead=0;
     (numRead=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+curOffset,MAX_READ_SIZE))>0;
    )
...
```

Comment: This question is a testament as to why doing assignments inside a conditional clause is a really bad idea....

Comment: Aside: you don't need to (and shouldn't) be casting the return value of `malloc()`.  If it's declared properly, it returns `void*`, which is assignable to any pointer type.  And if not, then you'll want to know and fix that!

Comment: OK, I'll make it NULL

Comment: @Andrew, let me guess, precedence?

Comment: Regardless, back up the comment list, read Andrew's comment. Then think about the expression+statement in your while conditional.

Comment: Hint: `numRead` is only going to be `0` or `1` in the currently-posted code.

Comment: OK, I get it, it's precedence. Is there any way to change this to perform the definition in the variable definition and assignment in the while condition or must I define the variable before the while?

Comment: Maybe [read() from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8975521/608639)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn You can add parenthesis to address the precedence, but how can you do error handling when you call `read` as part of the conditional clause of the `while`?

Comment: @Andrew, can you really fix this with parentheses? If so, show the code

Comment: `for (ssize_t numRead; (numRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf + curOffset, MAX_READ_SIZE))>0);)`, and as a bonus it will compile on a C compiler

Comment: It's amazing how many factually wrong comments there are here, when the issue is only one of precedence

Comment: The "bug" is that there's no such syntax as `while (ssize_t numRead=read(...))` in C language at all. And yet you tagged your question as [C]. Why is it tagged [C] and how did you even manage to compile it?

Comment: @WhozCraig, looks like you gave me some bonus gratuitous parentheses as well :)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn probably. Just tapped it out on a phone, but you the idea. If you still want the id local to the loop, a `for` is the only way to get there in C.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Not true.  You'll absolutely get an explicit `\n` in the input!

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Where are these bonus parentheses?

Comment: @Osiris, WhozCraig's solution should have been: `for (ssize_t numRead; (numRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf + curOffset, MAX_READ_SIZE))>0;)` Notice the missing right paren after the `0` and before the `;`

Comment: @WhozCraig, post your solution within the next several minutes, with the syntax error corrected and I will give you the *checkmark*. Otherwise, I'll give it to Toby since he is the only answer so far.

Comment: @Nominal Animal, notice the *Just for test purposes* comment on the fixed constant size of the buf

Comment: @Nominal, fair enough, another warning added to satisfy your request

Comment: Don't use compound expressions/statements.  They go wrong so often that I see about one a week on SO:(   Unclear, easy to get wrong and difficult to debug, such code should be split into multiple, individual statements with more temp vars for intermediate results.

Comment: @Martin, oh ye of little scope reduction desire :)

Comment: Apart from the precedence, there is another error lurking in here: `buf + curOffset + MAX_READ_SIZE` could exceed `BUF_SIZE`. The solution: sanitize your loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't narrow down the assignment enough:

```
while (ssize_t numRead=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+curOffset,MAX_READ_SIZE)>0)
```

That assigns the *result of the comparison* to `numRead`, i.e. 0 or 1.

What you want to assign is the result of `read`:

```
ssize_t numRead;
while ((numRead=read(STDIN_FILENO,buf+curOffset,MAX_READ_SIZE)) > 0)
```